# ms-access only show records when selecting certain item from dropdown

Tags: database, forms, database-design, ms-access-2013

I use MS-Access 2013 for this project.

Something I'm unable to find is how I can hide and show certain fields when something happens.

Let's be a little less vague. So, I have a dropdown of 5 items. Oral Exam, Written Exam, Exam on PC, External exam and revision.

All fields are the same for almost every possible selection in the dropdown apart from "exam on PC". Then some additional fields should be filled in, in the form. These are PC_Number amongst other things. The fields are "Yes/No" fields and simple input fields.

Is there a possibility to hide them when "exam on PC" isn't selected in the dropdown and show them when "exam on PC" is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very possible and very straightforward.

Lets say your drop down field is `Field1` and the field you want to hide or not is `Field2`

Simply add the following code to the `AfterUpdate` event

```
If me.Field1.value<>"Exam on PC" then
    me.Field2.visible=false
else
    me.Field2.Visible=true
end if
```